How to use Arial on matplotlib via Google Colab?
For context: some scientific journals demand the fonts of our graphs to be Arial, and since I use google colab to plot absolutely everything, I need to find a way to change my font to Arial globally.
I tried just use plt.rcParams['font.family'], but it yields a WARNING:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Font family 'Arial' not found.
I also tried different solutions, like installing with !wget and using font_manager and stuff (for reference, like this) but nothing seems to work.

first you may have to install Arial on Ubuntu because as I know Ubuntu doesn't have Arial. And it may need to use apt and probably install something like mscode-font (where ms measn Microsoft because Arial belong to Microsoft)

How to install Arial font (and other Windows fonts) in ubuntu? - Ask Ubuntu

Just an unchecked suggestion, hence not an answer. Place a copy of Arial in GDrive, mount GDrive in your Colab session and  ask Matplotlib to use the font file directly.

@gboffi this kinda works, thanks, but how do I change it globally? Should I use rcParams?

You now access Arial via a Path object, I don't know if you can set the relevant rc parameter to a Path, or if you must use FontManager in some complicated way. I could read the docs and the sources, but not now, sorry.

@gboffi no problem, you already helped a lot. If I find a way to do it globally I'll post here. Thank you so much!
